# Применение onblur к нескольким input

Tags: javascript

Достаточно глупый вопрос. 
Есть форма обратной связи, в форме есть несколько инпутов. К каждому инпуту нужно применить функцию на onblur, для того, чтобы выловить вводимые пользователем значения.
Подскажите, как это сделать, не обращаясь к каждому инпуту по id?
Такой код обращается только к первому инпуту.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onblur =  function() { 
    console.log(this);
}
```

Comment: jQuery не используется?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].onblur = function() {
        console.log(this);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', function() {
    console.log(this);
  }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На jQuery

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```